# how to replace the names controls with each other

Tags: vb.net

```
Button1.Name = cbName
Button2.Name = pickName
```

how can i make this work? be replaced by `Button1.Name` will be named `Button2` (pickName) and `Button2` will be named Button1 (cbName)

but so as not to tell me that it already exists controls in Form.

```
Button1.Name = Button1.Name.Replace("cb", "pick")
```

that is, after I execute the order, I expect to have

```
Button1.Name = pickName
Button2.Name = cbName
```

Comment: This is very vague.  Is this a web form or a windows form? I can guess, based on your code, that you have a checkbox and perhaps a picklist of some sort.  But what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes, Windows form. No checkbox, just a control button!

Comment: Why do you need to swap the button names? Perhaps the button's [`.Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag) property would be a better place to store some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear: are you just trying to do a name swap? In this case:

```
'Original names
Button1.Name = "cbName"
Button2.Name = "pickName"
Console.WriteLine("Case A: {0}, {1}", {Button1.Name, Button2.Name})

'Name swap
Dim tmp As String = Button1.Name
Button1.Name = Button2.Name
Button2.Name = tmp
Console.WriteLine("Case B: {0}, {1}", {Button1.Name, Button2.Name})
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: so simple, exactly !!!